# I am unable to show table from markdown field and I am using django-markdownx

Tags: django, markdown

when i enter markdown for the table tag in editor then it did nothing simply paste the same in the preview is there anybody for the help. I am using django-markdownx for the markdown text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are a non-standard Markdown feature. Therefore you need to enable the tables extension for them to work. In your `settings.py` file add the following:

```
MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = [
    'tables'
]
```